# Is It Possible to create a sql server in Cloud service?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I had created a web role in cloud service and it has feature to remote desktop by using this feature is it possible to Install sql server or any other softwares. if not possible why?

Answer (score 2):

Basically the cloud service is assigned any random box as per availability so any physical storage might be lost in case you stop and restart the service or many times those are restarted if any patch is installed. So always have separate SQL server (you can choose from cloud SQL server also) instance.

Comment: Thanks mahesh,You have any idea about Internal Load balancing feature in Azure Virtual machines

Comment: In cloud services you need to increase the instance automatically those will be load balanced

Answer (score 1):

SQL database (formerly SQL Azure)  is a SQL Server as a service offering on azure. It has almost all the same features as sql server and is fully managed with zero downtime. It supports almost all of the same TSQL  operations as the full blown sql server and you can easily migrate data, tables and stored procedures from an existing sql server to SQL Azure.

I'd use this instead of standing up your own sql server instance.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/

If you want to stand up your own sql server instance in azure then definately check out the resource manager templates, heres one for SQL Server 2014 always on !

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/sql-server-2014-alwayson-dsc

Answer (score 0):

Cloud service role instances are not suitable for durable storage of data. Expect any of the instances to disappear at any moment of time and then possibly be restarted on a totally clear VM. You should use something durable for persistent storage - that may be SQL Azure, Azure Storage or perhaps something else.

You might want to install SQL Server locally if for some reason your instance needs a local copy which can be accesses without network delays. You still should expect that your instance disappears at any moment. So installation should be automatic - such that when an instance is restarted on a new VM late on 1:00 AM on Sunday it works on its own. All valuable data must be periodically exported from that SQL Server instance to some durable storage, perhaps another SQL server. You could do that in code or setup some ready solution to do that.

Same applies to any other third-party software - its installation should work without human presence and useful data must be periodically exported to durable external storage. Expect to lose any data that is stored on the instance.